# Where does the "exit" method come from? Where is it documented?

Tags: sapui5

I've been following the [walkthrough tutorial](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/19453962b8074b7399372c65cbe05370) on Step 19: Reuse Dialogs. In the code below, I cannot figure out where the `exit` method comes from. I could not find anything in the [API reference for ManagedObject](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject).

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/base/ManagedObject",
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
], function (ManagedObject, Fragment) {
  "use strict";

  return ManagedObject.extend("sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.controller.HelloDialog", {
    constructor: function(oView) {
      this._oView = oView;
    },
    exit: function () {
      delete this._oView;
    },
    open: function() {
      // ...
    }
  });
});
```

If it is not documented in the API reference, how would someone know that `exit` is available to override and, more importantly, why not override `destroy` instead of `exit`? Something like:

```js
  // ...
  return ManagedObject.extend("sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.controller.HelloDialog", {
    constructor: function(oView) {
      this._oView = oView;
    },
    destroy: function() {
      delete this._oView;
      ManagedObject.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    open: function() {
      // ...
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook method `exit` is documented in **ManagedObject's subclass** `sap.ui.core.Element`: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.Element#methods/exit

> Hook method for cleaning up the element instance before destruction. Applications must not call this hook method directly, it is called by the framework when the element is destroyed.
> **Subclasses of Element should override this hook to implement any necessary cleanup.**
>
> ```js
> exit: function() {
>    // ... do any further cleanups of your subclass e.g. detach events...
>
>    if (Element.prototype.exit) {
>        Element.prototype.exit.apply(this, arguments);
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> For a more detailed description how to to use the exit hook, see Section [exit() Method in the documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/d4ac0edbc467483585d0c53a282505a5).

`sap.ui.base.Object` > `.EventProvider` > `.ManagedObject` > `sap.ui.core.Element` > `.Control` > ...

---

"Why not override `destroy` instead?" Well, one thing that the walkthrough doesn't explain is that there are mainly *two* roles when developing UI5 content:

- **Control**-/ **framework**-developer who provides a platform for application development
  → Overrides *protected* methods, such as `exit`.
- And **application** developer who purely consumes high level controls and APIs.
  → Should call *public* methods only, such as `destroy` if the control is no longer needed.

In step 19, by extending a low-level class such as `ManagedObject`, you're crossing the app developer role and providing a *hook* method for app developers who would call `myHelloDialog.destroy()`.

Comment: Thank you @Boghyon Hoffmann! Your descriptive answer has clarified everything.